# Example of non-noetherian algebras which are tensor products of noetherian algebras

Tags: commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, tensor-products, big-list, noetherian

We suppose all rings are commutative with unity.

I am looking for examples of a tensor product $B\otimes_A C$ which is not noetherian,
where $A$ is a noetherian ring and $B, C$ are noetherian $A$-algebras.

The more examples the better. In other words, I'm asking a big list of examples.

Comment: Since you have asked similar questions and I have given answers, maybe you want to accept this or delete this question? ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I wrote the more examples the better.

Comment: I opened a meta thread on this. 
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/why-was-this-question-asking-non-noetherian-examples-of-tensor-products-closed

Answer (score 12):

$\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}$ is not noetherian. For more examples from field extensions, see [math.SE/19426](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19426) and your own question [math.SE/694440](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694440). For example, if $K/F$ is a field extension which is not finitely generated, then $K \otimes_F K$ is not noetherian. From this one also gets more examples by localization, for example $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q$ is not noetherian, see [math.SE/684146](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684146). Likewise, if $k$ is a field, then $k[[x]] \otimes_k k[[y]]$ is not noetherian.