# Is $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q$ noetherian?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $p, q$ be prime numbers which may or may not be distinct.
Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb{Z}$.
Similarly for $\mathbb{Z}_q$.
Is $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q$ noetherian?

Answer (score 5):

No, since otherwise also the localization $p^{-1} q^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q = \mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_q$ is noetherian, which is not the case, since the transcendence degree of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite (see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19426)).

For $p=q$, I can give you an explicit example of an ideal which is not generated: The kernel $I$ of the multiplication $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_p$, i.e. $I = \langle a \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes a : a \in \mathbb{Z}_p \rangle$. I don't know a direct argument, but one can use
$$I/I^2 \cong \Omega^1_{\mathbb{Z}_p / \mathbb{Z}} \cong \Omega^1_{\mathbb{Z}[[X]]/(X-p) ~/\mathbb{Z}} \cong \Omega^1_{\mathbb{Z}[[X]]/\mathbb{Z}} /\langle X-p,d(X-p)  \rangle$$
and [MO/21189](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21189).

Comment: Could you explain what exactly $p^{-1} q^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q$ is?

Comment: If $A$ is a ring and $f \in A$, then $f^{-1} A := A_f$ is the localization of $A$ at (the multiplicative subset generated by) $f$.

Comment: So I suppose you mean $p^{-1} q^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q = 
p^{-1}(q^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q))$, right? 
Then could you explain how you prove that $p^{-1} q^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q = \mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_q$?

Comment: Use $p^{-1} Z_p = Q_p$ and general nonsense.

Comment: I understand $p^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Q}_p$.
Could you elaborate a bit on $p^{-1} q^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q = \mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_q$?

Comment: Use that $p^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Q}_p$ and that localizations commute with tensor products, and that $\mathbb{Q}$-linear is the same as $\mathbb{Z}$-linear, so that you can replace $\mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}_q$ by $\mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_q$.

Comment: "**$Q$-linear is the same as $Z$-linear, so that you can replace $\mathbb{Q}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}_q$ by $\mathbb{Q}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_q$.**"
 I'm afraid I don't understand. Could you please explain this?

Comment: Lemma: If $M,N$ are $S^{-1} R$-modules, then $M \otimes_{S^{-1} R} N = M \otimes_R N$. Proof: By the Yoneda Lemma, it suffices to prove that every $R$-bilinear map $M \times N \to T$ (with $T$ an $S^{-1} R$-module) is already $S^{-1} R$-bilinear. This is easy to check.

Comment: I have another question on the issue.
Let $S = \{p^nq^m \ |\ n, m = 0, 1, 2,\cdots \}$.
Then $S^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q) = \mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}_q$.
Are you saying that $\mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}_q = \mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}_q$?

Answer (score 3):

We assume all rings are commutative and have multiplicative identity elements.

**Notation**
Let $A$ be a ring, $B$ an $A$-algebra, $M$ an $A$-module.
Then we denote $M\otimes_A B$ by $M_B$.

**Lemma 1**
Let $A$ be a ring, $B$ an $A$-algebra.
Let $M$ and $N$ be $A$-modules.
Then $(M\otimes_A N)_B \cong M_B \otimes_B N_B$.

Proof:
$(M\otimes_A N)_B \cong (M \otimes_A N) \otimes_A B \cong M \otimes_A N_B \cong M \otimes_A (B\otimes_B N_B) \cong (M \otimes_A B) \otimes_B N_B) \cong M_B \otimes_B N_B$.

**Corollary**
Let $A$ be a ring, $S$ a multiplicative subset of $A$.
Let $M$ and $N$ be $A$-modules.
Then $S^{-1}(M\otimes_A N) \cong S^{-1}M \otimes_{S^{-1}A} S^{-1}N$.

Proof:
This is clear because $S^{-1}M \cong M\otimes_A S^{-1}A$, $S^{-1}N \cong N\otimes_A S^{-1}A$.

**Lemma 2**
Let $p$ be a prime number.
Let $S = \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$.
Then $S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Q}_p$.

Proof:
Let $x$ be a nonzero element of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
There exists an integer $n$ such that $p^n x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.
Hence $S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Q}_p$.

**Lemma 3**
Let $p, q$ be prime numbers which may or may not be distinct.
Let $S = \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$.
Then $S^{-1} (\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q) \cong \mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_q$.

Proof:
Clear by Lemma 2 and the corollary of Lemma 1.

**Proposition**
Let $p, q$ be prime numbers which may or may not be distinct.
Then $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_q$ is not noetherian.

Proof:
Otherwise $\mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_q$ is noetherian by Lemma 3.
However, this is not the case by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694440/proof-that-k-otimes-f-l-is-not-noetherian).

Comment: This is correct.