# Proof that $K\otimes_F L$ is not noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field and $K$ and $L$ be extension fields of $F$ such that  $\mathrm{tr.deg}_F(K) = \infty$ and $\mathrm{tr.deg}_F(L) = \infty$.

It seems to be proved that $K\otimes_F L$ is not noetherian by the following paper.

> P. Vámos, *On the minimal prime ideals of a tensor product of two fields*, Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 84 (1978), pp. 25-35.

However, I don't have an easy access to a university library. I would appreciate if someone would post the proof (which needs not be that of Vámos).

Comment: It should be noted that such a tensor product can be non-Noetherian even in the exact opposite situation. For example, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is not Noetherian.

Comment: In fact, Vámos proves that $K \otimes_F K$ is noetherian if and only if the intermediate fields of $K/F$ satisfy the ascending chain condition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a slight generalization of the relevant section in Vámos' paper.

**Lemma**: Let $F \subseteq E$ be a field extension and $A,B$ be two $E$-algebras $\neq 0$. If there is a strictly ascending chain of intermediate fields between $F$ and $E$, then $A \otimes_F B$ is not Noetherian.

Proof: Let $\{F_n\}$ be a strictly ascending chain of intermediate fields between $F$ and $F'$. For every $n \leq m$ we have a commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{c} & A \otimes_F B & \\  & \swarrow  ~~~~~~~ \searrow  \\ A \otimes_{F_n} B & \rightarrow & A \otimes_{F_m} B. \end{array}$$
Hence, if $I_n$ denotes the kernel of $A \otimes_F B \to A \otimes_{F_n} B$, we see that $\{I_n\}$ is an ascending chain of ideals. It is strictly ascending: Choose $f \in F_{n+1} \setminus F_n$. Then $f \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes f \in I_{n+1}$, but not $\in I_n$ since $f \otimes 1 \neq 1 \otimes f$ in $A \otimes_{F_n} B$ since $\{1,f\}$ is $F_n$-linearly independent in $A$ resp. $B$. $\square$

**Corollary**: Let $K,L$ be extension fields of $F$ such that $\mathrm{tr.deg}_F(K)$ and $\mathrm{tr.deg}_F(L)$ are infinite. Then $K \otimes_F L$ is not Noetherian.

Proof. Let $E$ be a rational function field over $F$ in countably many variables. Then $E$ embeds into $K$ and $L$, and there is a strictly ascending chain of intermediate fields between $F$ and $E$. Thus the Lemma applies. $\square$