# Is tensor product of completion Noetherian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is an algebra of finite type over a field $k$ and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$.
Let $\hat{A}$ denote the completion of $A$ along $\mathfrak{p}$.
Is is true that
$$ \hat{A} \otimes_k \hat{A} $$
is Noetherian?

Comment: don't think this holds in general see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19426/when-is-a-tensor-product-of-two-commutative-rings-noetherian?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I wouldn’t be so quick in judgement. For instance, the tensor product $A_{\mathfrak{p}} \otimes_k A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is Noetherian despite not satisfying the hypothesis of the question you pointed me to.